# JavaFX add Image to title of TitledPane css only

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-css

I need to add an image to title. I know how to do that in java code.
But I want to do that via css only.
I tried:

```
.titled-pane > .title{
  -fx-graphic: url("imgs/general/logo.png");
}
```

and

```
.titled-pane {
  -fx-graphic: url("imgs/general/logo.png");
}
```

But it did not help.

Update: Resources paths.

```
/src/main/resources/styles.css
/src/main/resources/imgs/general/logo.png
/src/main/resources/fxml/window.fxml
```

Comment: Where the image is located?Is the url you are using correct?Where the css file is located?

Comment: Url is correct. ccs file is located in src/main/resource folder next to imgs folder.

Comment: Css is located into it's own folder? `resources/css`? Add an image to see how they are located.Maybe we can solve this... :)

Comment: No. See updated question,

Comment: Try adding `/` before imgs.

Comment: did not help, Url path is correct. I used the same path for button's graphic and it's worked there.

Comment: I found an issue. I just don't specify stylesheet in fxml,

Answer (score 0):

Try this -fx-background-image: url("")

Comment: Did not help. Seem to be that any style does not work for title.